# PHP unset $_SESSION['variable'] also unsets local variable

Tags: php, session

I am having a problem when unsetting a session variable.

In one PHP script I create a session variable

```
$_SESSION['flash_message'] = "Information successfully added!";
```

Then I redirect the user to the home page and do the following:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);

if (isset($_SESSION['flash_message']) {
     $message = $_SESSION['flash_message'];
     echo $message;
     unset($_SESSION['flash_message']);
}
var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump($message);
```

The problem is that not only does this unset `$_SESSION['flash_message']` it also unsets `$message`.

If I don't unset anything then I get a response from all 3 `var_dump`s and the echo.

If I do:

```
if (empty($message)) {
 unset($_SESSION['flash_message']);
}
```

Then nothing gets unset and again I can see the value all 4 times;

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this kind of behavior?

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSSION);` one too many S's

Comment: works for me http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ef2-t7f

Comment: it works for me too outside of my application, so I know it is something in my application but I cant figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, if found a solution, although I am still not sure what exactly is causing this issue.

Anyway I am now using my Session class to handle the setting and unsetting of the message(as I should have done in the first place).

In my session class I now do this:

```
function __construct() {
    session_start();
    $this->check_message();
}

    public function message($msg=""){
    if(!empty($msg)){

        $_SESSION['message'] = $msg;
    }else{
        // get message
        return $this->message;
    }
}


    private function check_message(){

    if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){
        // Add it to an attribute and erase the stored version
        $this->message = $_SESSION['message'];
        unset($_SESSION['message']);
    }else{
        $this->message = "";
    }
}
```

In my controller I do this:

```
$session->message("Details successfully updated!");
```

And in my view:

```
$helper->display_message($errors, $session->message, $errors_heading);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the value of `register_globals`
You can set it to off in the .htaccess file

```
php_flag register_globals off
```

If that is **on**, `$_POST['example']` and `$_GET['example']` will both be accessable via `$example`.
Apply the **unset** to that logic, and you know why that var is unset

Comment: *This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.* [http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php]

Comment: With good reason I might add. It's just stupid that it works. But the TS never said anything about PHP version, and it sounds just like this :)

Comment: Thanks but I am running this on PHP5.5 so no register_globals